# Как собрать свой проект на Puthon для запуска на Андройд, т.е. создать apk файл, я использую PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Ребят может пожалуйста для новичка описать процесс сборки apk файла на Python?
Вот у меня есть файл main.py, как создать из него Андройд файл и запустить на телефоне

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout




class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Выбор цвета')
        self.btn = QPushButton('Кнопка')

        hbox = QVBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(hbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: тема обширная, советую почитать про BeeWare https://beeware.org/

Comment: и https://kivy.org/

Comment: Нет. Если хотите чего-то подобного - изучайте Kivy.